# PDO Sql statement order by error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php 
require('db_info.php');
$recordsPerPage = 5;
if (isset($_GET['page']))
  $curPage = $_GET['page'];
else
      $curPage = 1;
  $startIndex = ($curPage-1) * $recordsPerPage;

try {
       $pdoObject = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname;", $dbuser, $dbpass);
   $sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM usercom";
   $statement = $pdoObject->query($sql); 
   $record = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $pages = ceil($record['count(id)']/$recordsPerPage);

   $record=null;
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM usercom LIMIT $startIndex, $recordsPerPage ORDER BY date DESC";
   $statement = $pdoObject->query($sql);
   while ( $record = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
   echo '<p>'.$record['date'].'<br/>'.$record['userComment'].'<br/>';
                }


   $statement->closeCursor();

   $pdoObject = null;

   } catch (PDOException $e) {

   echo 'PDO Exception: '.$e->getMessage();
    die();

   }?></p>
```

I'm trying to fetch result from a database and use pagination. The problem is that the descending order asked in the statement never applies. Why isn't this working? If I don't add the line "ORDER BY date DESC" it works just fine, but when I do it prints error that I'm trying to fetch a non-object.

Comment: LIMIT goes in the end, not before ORDER BY

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Comment: print the query and see how it looks. Also, as Marek said, use backticks arround date.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax isn't quite correct,

Use this one instead,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usercom` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $startIndex, $recordsPerPage";
```

Comment: @user3665011: What not changed? An error? or the output? May be the limit range is not correct.

Comment: "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object"
I changed usercom to 'usercom' and date to 'date',but still..

Comment: Then it is PHP error not MySQL query. Above SQL query is fine.

Comment: I know,do you know how it can be fixed?

Comment: you cant use normal single quotes for table/column names ('usercom','date'), you must use backticks( ` usercom ` , ` date ` )